# New to mac and I my app store is acting up

Tags: mac-appstore

I just bought a Mac to try it out for the first time. I tried to DL a game from the app store just to try it out and I get this same "The item you’ve requested is not currently available in the U.S. store." error one just about every app I try to use.

What do?

I've tried to clear the cache, and change regions. It did not work.

[image]

Comment: Can you add the link to one of these applications so others can give it a try. This would help to figure out whether it's a general issue or something related to your specific setup.

Comment: Also I assume you have an Apple ID and are logged into the Store, right?

Comment: In what country is your Apple ID registered? In what country are you doing this?